# Set the interpolator for android animations in Java

Tags: java, android, android-animation

This seems very simple: I'm trying to set the interpolator to be used for an animation in my App. I need to set this in the Java code, not the XML (It will change according to various things).

From the android website, I've found `setInterpolator()`

However, I'm not sure how to use this.

I've tried just feeding in the interpolar name (ie. `BounceIterpolator`), but this did nothing.

I tried `R.anim.BounceIterpolator`, but Intellisense said `anim cannot be resolved or is not a field`.

So how can I set the interpolator from the Java?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67636215/479728

Answer (score 87, accepted):

```
setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
```

Answer (score 15):

```
anim.setInterpolator(context, android.R.anim.bounce_interpolator);
```

Answer (score 11):

### **Update:**

Android now supports real spring and physics within animations. Its part of a backward compatible lib. [Link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/physics-based-animation.html)

**For custom interpolators:**

1. Create a custom cubic bezier curve using this [awesome site](https://matthewlein.com/ceaser/). And get the control points for the curve.
2. `Interpolator customInterpolator = PathInterpolatorCompat.create(cpX1,cpX2,cpY1,cpY2)`
3. Add this customInterpolator to any of your animation.

Added a [gist](https://gist.github.com/amalChandran/6abc2f7cbd2643492e3fc45e9c3f4819).
Some [more here](https://medium.com/@preciselyamal/custom-interpolators-for-animation-on-android-using-pathinterpolatorcompat-a104486d2fb2#.oyij8ndpc).

Comment: Wow. I searched the entire internet for this answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [amalBit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39126423/2914140) I wrote an interpolator with a `PathInterpolator` for a `ProgressBar` in Kotlin.

```
val path = Path()
path.lineTo(0.1f, 0.2f)
path.lineTo(0.7f, 0.9f)
path.lineTo(1f, 1f)
val animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(progress_bar, "progress", 0, 100)
animation.duration = 2000
animation.interpolator = PathInterpolatorCompat.create(path)
animation.addListener(object : Animator.AnimatorListener {
    override fun onAnimationStart(animator: Animator) {}

    override fun onAnimationEnd(animator: Animator) {
        finish()
    }

    override fun onAnimationCancel(animator: Animator) {}

    override fun onAnimationRepeat(animator: Animator) {}
})
animation.start()
```

See more examples at https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.view.animation.PathInterpolator.