# how to use PathInterpolatorCompat

Tags: android, android-support-library

I'm trying to use `PathInterpolator` from `android.support.v4.view.animation.PathInterpolatorCompat`
because `PathInterpolator` won't work on my device API 18 since it was added in API 21.

I've downloaded the support repository, and included the following `build.gradle` under the app directory:

```
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0"
```

I'm trying to use it like this:

```
PathInterpolator p_interpolator = new PathInterpolator(.5f,1.0f);
```

However, in Android Studio it prompts the import from: `android.view.animation.PathInterpolator` instead of giving me an option for the compat version.

What do I need to do?

*Editor's Note: the right usage of `PathInterpolatorCompat` is (as @fernforce mentioned in a comment on the accepted answer):*

```
PathInterpolator p_interpolator = PathInterpolatorCompat.create(.5f,1.0f);
```

Comment: I tried including it manually: import android.support.v4.view.animation.PathInterpolatorCompat; but the "animation" part is not found. Maybe I could have setup my own class and broke out my old calculus textbook to achieve the darn solution.

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67636215/4797289

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PathInterpolatorCompat` is available in the support library since version 22.1.0. To fix that just change the gradle declaration to use the latest version:

```
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1"
```

For more informations see the Support Library v22.1 [announcement](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html).

Comment: This is the correct answer, I just don't have enough reputation to vote it. The implementation is as follows: Interpolator p_interpolator = PathInterpolatorCompat.create(0.5f,1.0f);

Comment: you can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67636215/4797289